# How to get to display database items in ejs/html using Nodejs/mongodb/mongoose?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Nodejs  / Mongo / Mongoose databse can get  and display to a page, but i cannot get it to display the items in html i.e. in a table format.

Here is the creation of database which works

```
app.post('/insert',   require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(),
function(req, res, next) {

 let name = req.user.username;

      Order.create({
              name: name,
            })
            .then(user => res.send(user))
            .catch(err => res.send(err));
            res.redirect('/');
    });
```

This is server.js which works by displaying the database items on a blank orders page.

```
  app.get('/orders',
      function(req, res) {

     let name = req.user.username;

        Order.findOne( {name: name })
           .then(user => res.send(user))
            .catch(err => res.send(err));
        });
```

I tried the below in server.js

```
  app.get('/orders',
    require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(),
    function(req, res){
      res.render('orders', { user: req.user });
    });
```

And in ejs/html

```
  <tr>
        <td>Style</td>
        <td><%= name %></td>
    </tr>
```

But receive the error "name is not defined".

What do i need to do to display the items in html?
How do i define the name variable?

Answer (score 0):

Name of the variable while accessing it in the ejs file must be same as what you have passed in the render function.
Code will look like (ejs):

```
<tr>
        <td>Style</td>
        <td><%= user %></td>
    </tr>
```